# get records for the last 7 days in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table in `hive` like below. I want to select `insertdate`, `customer_id` from this table where `insertdate` is `current_date - 7 days`.

`original table`

```
+------------------------+--------------+
|       insertdate       | customer_id  |
+------------------------+--------------+
| 2018-04-21 04:00:00.0  | 39550695     |
| 2018-04-22 04:00:00.0  | 38841612     |
| 2018-04-23 03:59:00.0  | 23100419     |
| 2018-04-24 03:58:00.0  | 39550688     |
| 2018-04-25 03:58:00.0  | 39550691     |
| 2018-05-12 03:57:00.0  | 39550685     |
| 2018-05-13 03:57:00.0  | 39550687     |
| 2018-05-14 03:57:00.0  | 39550677     |
| 2018-05-14 03:56:00.0  | 30254216     |
| 2018-05-14 03:56:00.0  | 39550668     |
+------------------------+--------------+
```

`expected result`

```
+------------------------+--------------+
|       insertdate       | customer_id  |
+------------------------+--------------+
| 2018-05-12 03:57:00.0  | 39550685     |
| 2018-05-13 03:57:00.0  | 39550687     |
| 2018-05-14 03:57:00.0  | 39550677     |
| 2018-05-14 03:56:00.0  | 30254216     |
| 2018-05-14 03:56:00.0  | 39550668     |
+------------------------+--------------+
```

But I am getting empty results when I try the following

```
select insert_date, customer_id from table where insert_date = date_sub(current_date, 7);

select insert_date, customer_id from table whereinsert_date = date_sub(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),'yyyy-MM-dd'), 7);
```

For both the above queries I got empty results.

What am I doing wrong here and how to get the correct result?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you need data for the past 7 days, use

```
select insert_date, customer_id 
from table 
where to_date(insert_date) >= date_sub(current_date, 7) 
and to_date(insert_date) < current_date
```

The reason your query doesn't show results is because of the comparison between datetime format and date.

Comment: How can i include Timestamp here? Suppose i want seven days data. 
If current_date is 7/25/2022 4PM i need data till 7/18/2022 4PM.
If i just take dates i will get all records from 7/18/2022.